# I'm new at cron and scrapy. // cron not working in AWS. (it's fine in my local environment)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, scrapy

**In AWS,**

```
> source /home/ubuntu/envv/bin/activate && cd /srv/MyFirstCrawler/scraper && scrapy crawl blondieshop_spider
```

- my virtualenv is envv,
- my project is scrapy + django, project name is
  MyFirstCrawler,
- above cron is working when i type in command line.
  but not working in cron..

when i typed 'service cron status'

> Sep 21 05:01:01 ip-172-31-5-186 CRON[6473]: pam_unix(cron:session):
> session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0) Sep 21 05:01:01
> ip-172-31-5-186 CRON[6474]: (ubuntu) CMD (source     >
> /home/ubuntu/envv/bin/activate && cd /srv/MyFirstCrawler/scraper &&
> scrapy crawl blondieshop_spider) Sep 21 05:01:01 ip-172-31-5-186
> CRON[6473]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu

**i really can't figure out what's wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem myself. It was not scrapy problem. The only way I found to see detail log of cron is using mailbox.

After cat `/var/spool/mail/yourbox`, I saw source doesn't work.

In Ubuntu, shell should be `bin/bash` not `bin/sh`.